# insmod error: Unknown symbol ipv6_ext_hdr

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

There is an error when I insert a kernel module using `insmod data/linux/openvswitch.ko` in the kernel. The error show is as shown below:

```
insmod: error inserting 'datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

The output of `dmesg | tail`, is:

```
openvswitch: Unknown symbol ipv6_ext_hdr
```

Does anybody know anything about it?
My kernel is:

```
Linux version 2.6.32_1-14-0-0 (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #2 SMP
```

Comment: Is ipv6 built inside kernel or loaded as modules?

Comment: Thanks, yes, just as you said, i found the problem.

Comment: Added this as answer for others.

Comment: That's seem strange because that function depends only on `CONFIG_NET` kernel paremeter which is usually set to `y` (built-in in kernel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your ipv6 support in Linux kernel. Make it built-in in kernel or enable it as module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compile the module again using the current linux kernel

Comment: Thanks, i will try to change the kernel version

Comment: how does current kernel version help if you have ipv6 disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The openvswitch kernel module has a number of dependencies.  If you use

```
modprobe openvswitch
```

rather than insmod, linux will take care of loading the dependent modules.